# SQL remove character from string

Tags: sql

I am subtracting the date part from a string; sometimes there is an extra character at the end like here:

```
Mon,  1 Oct 2011 10:51:52 -0400%
```

Sometimes, the date is fine and does not have to be trimmed:

```
Mon,  21 Oct 2011 10:51:52 -0400
```

How do I remove this last character ( % in this example) in the case that the character does exist?

Comment: what column type are your dates being stored in?  I don't think you would have this issue if it were stored in a `datetime`

Comment: it is actually an nvarchar.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE` if you know the character.

```
REPLACE(@input, '%', '')
```

If you have a fixed format for everything before the additional character, you can use `CHARINDEX` to find the last ':', then get a `SUBSTRING` of the first character up to the known good characters (up to the -0400 in your case):

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(50) = 'Mon,  1 Oct 2011 10:51:52 -0400%'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, 1, LEN(@Input) - CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(@Input)) + 9)
```

This returns:

```
Mon,  1 Oct 2011 10:51:52 -0400
```